# JSF Composite Component script doesn't get included when it's added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I've got a composite JSF component for multi language text input - it renders multiple inputs and switches their visibility using JS. I'm adding the JS script using

```
<h:outputScript name="custom/multiLangInput.js" target="body"/>
```

in `<composite:implementation>`. I do not wish to put it inline, because of a posibility of multiple components on one page - I wish to still have only one script instance. It works well, but the problem is when I have part of a page (including this custom tag) loaded on ajax request - it renders the component correctly, but the script doesn't get included and language switching doesn't work correctly. 
How can I get to work while still restricting it to one script instance per page? I do not wish to include the script hardcoded on the page/in the theme - I want the composite tag to be universal and reusable.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a similar notation as you've put here for the same reason of only loading a JS file once.  The only difference I can see is that I always set the target to head, not body.

```
<h:outputScript name="default/vendor/pikaday/js/pikaday.js"
            target="head" />
```